# Trying to add foreign key and an error occured "errno: 150 'Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed'"

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb, innodb

Primary key column `id_kegiatan` on the table that referenced as foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE `Kegiatan` (
  `id_kegiatan` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_program` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nama_kegiatan` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_kegiatan`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Table that the column `id_kegiatan` I have tried to set into foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE `Perjalanan_Dinas` (
  `id_dinas` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_kegiatan` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_satker` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nomor_surat_tugas` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nomor_sp2d` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tanggal_surat_tugas` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `tanggal_mulai_dinas` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `tanggal_selesai_dinas` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `tujuan_dinas` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_dinas`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Foreign key query:

```
ALTER TABLE Perjalanan_Dinas ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN_id_kegiatan FOREIGN KEY (`id_kegiatan`) REFERENCES `Kegiatan`(`id_kegiatan`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

An error occured like this:
`#1025 - Error on rename of './database/#sql-50ec_548' to './database/Perjalanan_Dinas' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`

I have added index to set the 'id' column on the table that was meant to be a foreign key column, ensured the data type to be the same, but still an error occured.

Version: 10.4.28-MariaDB (phpmyadmin)

Comment: once the extra commas are removed, this works just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/af7iAlKx  please edit your question to show actual output of `select version();` and `show create table table_reference;` and `show create table table_foreign;`

Comment: you mean extra commas after the `NOT NULL`?. I'm actually using phpmyadmin to set it as foreign key.

Comment: @ysth I've added the actual output. Please take a look into it, thanks.

Comment: something is different in your environment; it should work just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/VOiwmqrd

Comment: I tried to export the db, delete the db, and then tried to import it again. Running the same query to add the foreign key into the table, it's running fine. Damn I spent 2 hours and just recently resolved this by recreating the db. I agree with you @ysth, when I tried to show 'show engine innodb status' it kept showing the old query that has the same error. Probably some cache issues.